# Running Ubuntu in VirtualBox on a 4k monitor feels extremely laggy

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Specs:

- Host OS: Windows 10
- Guest OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 (of course, I've installed the VirtualBox guest package in the guest OS)
- 3D acceleration enabled in VirtualBox, 128MB (max) video RAM
- Host specs: Intel i5-8400, 16GB RAM

Symptoms:

- input lag
- visual lag
- screen tearing when dragging windows
- everything generally slow

I remember years ago, on a much worse PC, I could run a Linux VM through VBox that would feel snappy. Now I'm trying to run Ubuntu on a better PC and everything has enormous input and visual update lag.

The only difference might be that I now have a 4K monitor? However, I've set Ubuntu's resolution to 1080p, and am running it in scaled mode as a window. I get slightly more acceptable performance in fullscreen mode.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Looking at the Performance tab of the Task Manager (while running the VM), is anything maxed out (e.g. cpu)?

Comment: @Gantendo (edited in the specs, intel i5 8400 & 16GB RAM) -- my memory seems to be maxed out for some reason

Comment: Look at what is consuming the RAM. Perhaps you can assign less RAM to the VM. https://i.imgur.com/GY0DoAz.png It might be wise to buy some more RAM anyway. Or borrow some (if possible) and check if it solves the problem.

Comment: Yeah I tried to look at it, but no process was consuming anything that could account for that used. But I fixed it with a random guess. I disabled the Hyper-V Windows feature. Apparently that reserves 65% of your system RAM for some reason lmao.

Still the same thing with my VirtualBox Ubuntu VM however.

Answer (score 2):

I just installed VMWare Player (which is free of charge). Everything works smoothly straight out of the box. 4K resolution as if running natively. Neither Hyper-V nor VirtualBox approached anywhere near this level of performance, I'm impressed and recommend this to anyone reading this post.

Of course, I'll accept the answer that *actually answers the question* if someone posts it, but this solved my actual problem.